# How can i add a property to an TS internal object?

Tags: typescript

I wanna add a property declaration to window.history object, but got a TS error hint

my code:

```
const historyInstance = createHashHistory(); // npm hoistory module
window.history.historyInstance = historyInstance;
//              ↑ error occurred in there
```

my `types.ts` is:

```
interface IHistory extends History {
  historyInstance: any;
}

interface Window {
  history: IHistory;
// ↑ (property) Window.history: History
// All declarations of 'history' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
// Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property // 'history' must be of type 'History', but here has type 'IHistory'.ts(2717)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adapting `Window` interface try to adapt `History` interface. Create a new `*.d.ts` file e.g. in your case maybe `history.d.ts`. Add following content:

```js
export = global;

declare global {
  interface History {
    historyInstance: any;
  }
}
```

You should put the newly created `history.d.ts` into a `types/` folder, and then you have to modify your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./types"],
    ...
  }
}
```

Folderstructur would be like:

```
types/
  |--- history.d.ts
tsconfig.json
```